# Is there a comprehensive list of non-light novels made into Anime?

Tags: anime-history

My family and I have been watching a lot of Anime lately, and I've noticed that some of the most well-written ones tend to be adapted from full length novels, rather than from light novels or mangas.   Don't get me wrong, many of the ones based on light novels or manga are also great, but the quality of the writing on ones based on full novels, like for example [Moribito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moribito_series) or [Twelve Kingdoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Kingdoms) tend to have a higher level of world building and deeper more original characters on average.  This helps because there are so many overused and boring character tropes often with paper thin plot concepts in not a small number of Anime series.

I know [Wikipedia has an extensive list of light novel adaptations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Anime_and_manga_based_on_light_novels) which I'm sure I will be mining at some point or another.  But what I really want is an extensive or comprehensive list of novels that have been made into Anime series and/or films.

Does anyone know of an extensive or comprehensive list of Novels made into Anime series?

Comment: Maybe this question is out of bounds because of some custom or another of this stack exchange site.  If so my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anime database sites like MyAnimeList, AniList, Anime-Planet, etc. have a "Source:" field, which indicates the type of medium that the anime was adapted from (if any).

Fortunately for your use case, these sites do appear to distinguish between "Novel" and "Light Novel". For example, [AniList's entry for Morbito](https://anilist.co/anime/1827/Seirei-no-Moribito) lists it as "Source: Novel". Meanwhile, entries for anime that were adapated from light novels, such as [Toaru Majutsu no Index](https://anilist.co/anime/4654/Toaru-Majutsu-no-Index/), display "Source: Light Novel".

So, to get a comprehensive list of anime adapted from non-light novels, searching on these sites and filtering based on source criteria should get you what you want. For example:

- AniList search: https://anilist.co/search/anime?source=NOVEL
- Anime-Planet search: https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/tags/based-on-a-novel